# How do I determine whether or not a stock is DTC-eligible?

Tags: united-states, stocks, penny-stocks, settling-and-clearing

From my understanding, exchange-listed stocks are all DTC-eligible (DTC meaning [Depository Trust Company](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depository_Trust_Company)), so my question is more about the securities that trade over-the-counter.

How can I check whether or not the stock of a particular company is DTC-eligible? I know that I could ask the investor relations department of the company, as companies are usually proud of their stock's DTC eligibility. But is there a central organization where DTC eligibility is recorded? Is there a better way I can check whether or not a stock is DTC-eligible?

Comment: Could you please define "DTC"?

Comment: @ChrisW.Rea DTC is the Depository Trust Company.

Comment: Ah, good to know. (Here in Canada, DTC most often implies "Dividend Tax Credit" when talking about stocks; i.e. a tax-advantaged form of distribution income.)

Answer (score 0):

contact their transfer agent, they should know if the stock is DTC eligible. Please make sure to not let them confuse DTC with DWAC eligibility. A stock will have no trades or quotes if not DTC eligible